# printf of a size_t variable with lld, ld and d type identifiers

Tags: c, printf

I wrote this tiny code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    size_t temp;
    temp = 100;

    printf("lld=%lld, ld=%ld, u=%u\n", temp, temp, temp);

    return 0;
}
```

I am running this on a **i386 GNU/Linux** machine with **gcc version 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52)**. This is the output that I got:

```
lld=429496729700, ld=100, u=7993461
```

I can understand that the first (`lld`) was printed as garbage because the `printf` tries to print 8 bytes (for `signed long long` as signified by `lld`) when only 4 bytes are available from variable `temp`.
But, I fail to understand why the last identifier, `u` is getting printed as garbage - whereas, in my understanding this is the closest applicable identifier for `size_t`.

Here I have assumed that `size_t` is `unsigned int` (which is signed 4 bytes for my i386).

Now, I did a little tweaking with the `printf` line:

```
...
printf("ld=%ld, u=%u, lld=%lld\n", temp, temp, temp);
...
```

and I have a perfectly fine answer (except the `lld` part).

```
ld=100, u=100, lld=34331653576851556
```

Can someone please help me in understanding what exactly am I missing here?

Thanks a lot for any help!

*[side note: I tried switching optimization using `gcc -O[0,2]` tag on/off without any difference in the observation.]*

Comment: The -Wformat option will probably detect this incompatibility for you.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the input - but, I was deliberately using wrong specifiers. I actually wanted to know how `printf` was consuming the elements on the stack. In fact, I think -Wall would have the same thing as well. Nevertheless, thanks a lot.

Comment: I realise that it was deliberate; but my point was that if the intention was to observe the compiler's behaviour, the -Wformat option demonstrates alternative (and safer) behaviour, which may have been of interest to someone, even if you were already aware of it. -Wall did not include -Wformat on older versions of GCC.

Comment: @Clifford Right .. I should have realized that. Thanks a lot for clarification.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's because what you've pushed on the stack is three 32-bit values and your format string tries to use four of them or, more accurately, one 64-bit value and two 32-bit values.

In the first case, the `lld` sucks up two 32-bit values, the `ld` sucks up the third one and the `u` gets whatever happens to be on the stack after that, which could really be anything.

When you change the order of the format specifiers in the string, it works differently because the `ld` sucks up the first 32-bit value, the `u` sucks up the second and the `lld` sucks up the third *plus* whatever happens to be on the stack after that. That's why you're getting different values, it's a data alignment/availability issue.

You can see this in action with the first value. 429496729700 is equal to `(4294967296 + 1) * 100`, i.e., (2<sup>32</sup>+1)*100. Your code snippet

```
printf("lld=%lld, ld=%ld, u=%u\n", temp, temp, temp);
```

actually has the following effect:

```
What you pass     Stack     What printf() uses
-------------     -----     ------------------
                 +-----+
100              | 100 | \
                 +-----+  = 64-bit value for %lld.
100              | 100 | /
                 +-----+
100              | 100 |    32-bit value for %ld.
                 +-----+
                 | ?   |    32-bit value for %u (could be anything).
                 +-----+
```

In the second case

```
printf("ld=%ld, u=%u, lld=%lld\n", temp, temp, temp);
```

the following occurs:

```
What you pass     Stack     What printf() uses
-------------     -----     ------------------
                 +-----+
100              | 100 |    32-bit value for %ld.
                 +-----+
100              | 100 |    32-bit value for %u.
                 +-----+
100              | 100 | \
                 +-----+  = 64-bit value for %lld (could be anything).
                 | ?   | /
                 +-----+
```

Comment: Yup, this sounds to perfectly the answer I was looking for. I read through the assembly code and it too does what you have mentioned (the part of pushing 3 variables of 32 byte on stack). I just could not confirm how printf was consuming them. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 11):

Your code aptly demonstrates Undefined Behavior. Note that in case of variadic arguments no type checking is done for parameters. This is when an explicit cast becomes necessary. In fact the following should therefore be used:

```
 printf("lld=%lld, ld=%ld, u=%u\n", 
         (unsigned long long)temp, 
         (unsigned long)temp, 
         (unsigned int)temp);
```

As an aside remember the specifier for `size_t` is `z`. So:

```
 printf("zd=%zd\n", temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing to printf the wrong number of bytes. %lld requires a larger integer, in your case the way %lld taked its argument is completely messed up, since it would expect a 64-bit value.

Answer (score 0):

paxdiablo's answer is reasonable in the author's environment. However, on my machine(x86_64 Linux), I got three "100" outputed in each type of the two printf line. So, type mismatch in printf actually invokes **undefined behavior**. In a specific running environment, maybe you can find an owesome explanation for the weird output results, but it's not universal.

The stack-based model is not always applicable, many modern calling conventions pass the first few ordinary values in registers, not on the stack. See also the bizarre situation asked [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571175/why-are-the-int-and-float-passed-in-printf-going-to-the-wrong-positions-in-the-f).

In conclusion, we should avoid the mismatch type identifiers usage in printf. And when we meet weird output of printf, don't forget to check if we have used right type identifiers for all of the variables.