# Strange printf behavior

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

```
        std::vector<DWORD64> v;
        for(size_t i = init; i < pageSize; ++i)
            v.push_back(i);

        DWORD64 last =  *(v.rbegin());
        DWORD64 first = *(v.begin());

        printf("%d %d \n", last, first);
        printf("%d %d \n", first, last);
```

outputs:

```
4095 0
0 0
```

I can't understand why this printf behaves like that? Neither init or pageSize is 0.
I understand that %d is not valid for unsigned long long, but what bothers me is that printf's behavior changes when argument's order change.

Comment: What are the actual values of `first` and `last`, and what are the sizes of `int` and `DWORD64` on your system?  Incidentally, if you find an explanation for the behavior, I hope you're not planning to make any real use of it.

Comment: No - that was just experimenting :)

Comment: So what are the actual values of ... [see above]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Neither init or pageSize is 0.

Nor is `%d` a suitable format string specifier for a 64-bit value, I'd bet :-)

More than likely, you'll need to use `%ld` (if your longs are 64 bit) or `%lld` (if your long longs are 64 bit) or the fixed-width specifier macros from the latest C standard that I can never remember off the top of my head, assuming they're available in your environment :-)

That whole problem would probably disappear if you embraced C++ rather than that half-ground which many coders seem to exist in (using legacy stuff like `stdio.h` when  better alternatives are available). You should use the type-aware:

```
std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
```

It also helps to have a compiler that's a bit intelligent, and ensure you *use* that intelligence:

```
pax$ cat qq.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cstdio>

    int main (void) {
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.push_back (111142);
        v.push_back (314159);
        long long a = *(v.begin());
        long long b = *(v.rbegin());
        printf ("%6d %6d, a then b, bad\n", a, b);
        printf ("%6d %6d, b then a, bad\n", b, a);
        std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ", good\n";
        return 0;
    }

pax$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -o qq qq.cpp
    qq.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    qq.cpp:11: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2
        has type 'long long int'
    qq.cpp:11: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 3
        has type 'long long int'
    : : : : :
    qq.cpp:12: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 3
        has type 'long long int'

pax$ ./qq
    111142 0,      a then b, bad
    314159 0,      b then a, bad
    111142 314159, good
```

For those truly interested in the mechanics as to why the values change based on their order in the `printf`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers/2424554#2424554).

It goes into detail about what things (and more importantly, the sizes of those things) get pushed on the stack, comparing them with what you told `printf` would be there.

Long story writ short: you lied to `printf` so it treated you the same way your significant other would, had you been caught lying to them :-)

Comment: +1, one thing that bothers me is why the first number of the second `printf` is zero. My best guess at the moment is that the lower bits are zero, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Exactly - this is what bothers me too. Otherwise it's understandable.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, that's a plausible explanation, you can confirm it by just changing the `%d`s to the correct strings and getting the real values.

Comment: I'm aware of all this stuff :) That cout is a better choice. I was just surprised by this undefined behavior that depends on argument's order.

Comment: If you insist on using `printf` with an integer type for which you don't know the right format, you can use a format that you do know and convert the arguments.  For example, assuming the argument values are within the range of `long long`, and assuming your `printf` implementation supports `%lld`, you could write `printf("%lld %lld\n", last, first);

Comment: @kka, I've added a link to an earlier answer of mine that should explain it. It took me a while to find it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers/2424554#2424554

Comment: @kka, the argument order unsurprisingly matters, because the next argument starts where the prvious ends :)

BTE, since it's a `c++` code, one may also consider using iostreams for ouput.

Comment: @paxdiablo, man that's a nice answer you've linked (seriously), I've just said that in one sentence, but the sentence would never get an upvote :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, it just did :)

Comment: @kka ;-)) Actually, no, not the sentence I was referring to.

Comment: A year and a half later, I come back and read my own comment and see that I left out the cast operators. What I *meant* is that you can write `printf("%lld %lld\n", (long long)last, (long long)first);` (or the appropriate C++-specific cast operator if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

First printf in fact prints the LO and HI DWORDs of the DWORD64 variable `last` (which is 4095, i believe). Second printf prints the LO and HI DWORDs of the DWORD64 variable `first` (which is 0). The second DWORD64 parameter is ignored in both lines...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is in the environment you're targetting `%d` is not for 64-bit quantities.  Try `%I64`.

Comment: Or try `std::cout << first << last`. :-)

Comment: std::cout works fine because the compiler will choose the right overload basing on first and last's type - what concerns me is why in case of an invalid specified type it behaves differently depending on argument's order. It is truly an "undefined behavior" :)