# What is the difference between %d and %*d in c language?

Tags: c, integer

What is `%*d` ? I know that `%d` is used for `integers`, so I think `%*d` also must related to integer only? What is the purpose of it? What does it do?

```
int a=10,b=20;
printf("\n%d%d",a,b);
printf("\n%*d%*d",a,b);
```

Result is

```
10 20 
1775 1775
```

Comment: Looks like a width specifier: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @Mysticial You should write that as an answer..

Comment: @Ben, it's just a link - which doesn't qualify as an answer. I'm too  lazy to expand on it...

Comment: @Ben, clearly it does deserve downvotes.  The answer is *immediately* available simply by reading the documentation.

Comment: @CarlNorum Pretty much all questions are answered by reading some documentation somewhere. There wouldn't be a need for SO if it was just simple as that.

Comment: @Mystical Is it really related to width specifier?

Comment: For the downvotes, it _could_ be justified by "this question does not show any research effort ..." but I tend to cut newbies a little slack though, unlike guga, I'm feeling too indifferent this morning to post a reversal vote :-). That last `printf` by the way is undefined behaviour since you should pass _four_ arguments.

Answer (score 19):

The `%*d` in a `printf` allows you to use a *variable* to control the field width, along the lines of:

```
int wid = 4;
printf ("%*d\n", wid, 42);
```

which will give you:

```
..42
```

(with each of those `.` characters being a space). The `*` consumes one argument `wid` and the `d` consumes the `42`.

The form you have, like:

```
printf ("%*d %*d\n", a, b);
```

is undefined behaviour as per the standard, since you should be providing *four* arguments after the format string, not two (and good compilers like `gcc` will tell you about this if you bump up the warning level). From `C11 7.20.6 Formatted input/output functions`:

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.

It should be something like:

```
printf ("%*d %*d\n", 4, a, 4, b);
```

And the reason you're getting the weird output is due to that undefined behaviour. [This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers/2424554#2424554) shows you the sort of things that can go wrong (and why) when you don't follow the rules, especially pertaining to this situation.

Now I wouldn't expect this to be a misalignment issue since you're using `int` for all data types but, as with all undefined behaviour, *anything* can happen.

Answer (score 13):

When used with scanf() functions, it means that an integer is parsed, but the result is not stored anywhere.

When used with printf() functions, it means the width argument is specified by the next format argument.

Answer (score 5):

The * is used as an indication that the width is passed as a parameter of printf

Comment: So why does it produce output 1775 1775?

Comment: printf is a variable argument function, so when the format string is parsed, it looks for an integer representing the width of the first value, the value itself, the width of the second value and the second value. Because you are only passing 2 values, the values used are undefined. Try using 4 meaningful values and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

in "%*d", the first argument is defined as the total width of the output, the second argument is taken as normal integer.
for the below program

```
int x=6,p=10;
printf("%*d",x,p);
output: "    10"
```

the first argument ta passed for *, that defines the total width of the output... in this case, width is passed as 6. so the length of the entire output will be 5.
now to the number 10, two places are required (1 and 0, total 2). so remaining 5-2=3 empty string or '\0' or NULL character will be concatenated before the actual output