# Can anyone explain this and also interchange " printf("n=%**d\n", n, l);" and explain how it works?i try it and print *d=n

Tags: c

Can anyone explain this and also interchange " printf("n=%**d\n", n, l);" and explain how it works? i try it and print *d=n

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n=5,l=9;
printf("n=%**d\n", l, n);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running both versions and seeing what happens? If you have, then share that information in the question.

Comment: Are the 2 asterisks a typo? What is the desired result? Try `printf("n=%*d\n", l, n);`

Comment: What is the second `*` for?

Comment: You can read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937052/what-is-the-difference-between-d-and-d-in-c-language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between %d and %\*d in c language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937052/what-is-the-difference-between-d-and-d-in-c-language)

Comment: And what does the interchanged version print? Clarify what is output by each version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax:

```
printf("n=%**d\n", l, n);
```

is incorrect and possibly a typo. It must have only a single asterisk (*). And it defines the minimum field width in formatting.

The correct syntax:

```
printf("n=%*d\n", l, n);
```

Will print `l` sized whitespaces. The `n` will be printed with right-justified mode. In a more clear way to comprehend:

Assuming `l` is 9 and `n` is 5555 (and `_` as spaces):

```
n=_____5555 // right justified, padded 9 times with spaces
```

Again, assuming `l` is the same and `n` is 5, then output will be:

```
n=________5 // still right justified
```

**Note:** You may try using `%s` for printing a char array.

It's used to format output for better look.

Comment: i try it and print *d=n

Comment: No, you've used double asterisk. Remove one.

Comment: @MohamedAbdullah, undefined behavior notwithstanding, I find it highly doubtful that your implementation prints `*d=n` when it processes the `printf` call presented in the question.  I would be prepared to believe that it prints `n=*d`, but that can be explained only in a reverse-engineering sense, for the behavior is, again, undefined.