# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with fscanf

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

I have a file inp which looks like:

```
123.456 one
111.111 two
222.222 three
444.444 four
```

I'm trying to read this file like:

```
while(fscanf(inp, "%s %s", s1, s2) != EOF)
```

Where `123.456` stores in `s1` (string) and `"one"` stores in `s2` (string).

But I get this error:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0x48)
```

Any idea why or how to fix this error?

Here is my whole code:

```
int main(void)
{
FILE *inp;
char s1[15];
char s2[8];

inp = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");

while(fscanf(inp, "%s %s", s1, s2) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s", s1);
}

return 0;
}
```

My debugging area shows that "123.456" is stored into s1 and "one" is stored into s2.

Comment: Show us how you declare `s1` and `s2`

Comment: Edited my original post to show s1 and s2 declaration.

Comment: where did you open the file - just post the whole code

Comment: Edited my original post to show my entire main function.

Comment: working on my setup [after adding the necessary std includes]. try rebuilding with debug and put a backtrace

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue either. Everything works fine on my system.

Comment: Consider `fscanf(inp, "%14s %7s", s1, s2) != 2)` to insure the scan is not writing where it shouldn't and that one indeed did scan 2 strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that code, other than the missing `stdio.h` include <sup>(a)</sup>. Therefore your problem either lies elsewhere (such as if you're compiling a *different* file) or your compiler is buggy (unlikely).

You can find out if it's the first one by simply making a minor change:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE *inp;
    char s1[15];
    char s2[8];

    puts ("Hello from Pax");
    inp = fopen ("inputfile.txt", "r");
    if (inp == NULL) {
        puts ("Couldn't open input file");
    } else {
        while (fscanf (inp, "%s %s", s1, s2) != EOF) {
            printf ("[%s] [%s]\n", s1, s2);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and seeing if the new message comes out. The change I'm suggesting for debugging is simply the `Hello from Pax` output but I've cleaned up the code a little more as well to catch some possible problems.

On my system, that code outputs:

```
Hello from Pax
[123.456] [one]
[111.111] [two]
[222.222] [three]
[444.444] [four]
```

as expected.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> One *possibility* to watch out for is missing include files in systems where `int` and pointers are different widths. If you have a compiler that assumes unprototyped functions accept `int` arguments, that may lead to parameters being extracted from the wrong place on the stack.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers/2424554#2424554) shows this particular little foible in action for mismatched `printf` format specifiers and it's possible you may see the same behaviour from `fscanf` since it uses the same feature.

But that's just educated supposition on my part, it may not apply here.