# c pow function printing wrong value but function returns correct results

Tags: c, windows

I have done a little function that converts hex colour values to rgb values in c.

The function is working correctly, if I pass it in  "#008080" I get:

```
HEX: #008080 RGB: 0, 128, 128
```

The issue I am having is when I am trying to print the value returned by pow() (for debugging purposes) this is what I get:

```
EX::: 0
POWER::: 0.000000
EX::: 1
POWER::: 0.000000
EX::: 0
POWER::: 0.000000
EX::: 1
POWER::: 0.000000
EX::: 0
POWER::: 0.000000
EX::: 1
POWER::: 0.00000
```

This is the code that outputs this:

```
int num = 0;
char c;
double power;

for (int i = strlen(hexString), ex = 0; i > 0; i--, ex++) {
    c = hexString[i - 1];
    power = pow(16.0, ex);
    printf("EX::: %d\n", ex);
    printf("POWER::: %lf\n", power);       
    num += convertHexCharToDec(&c) * power;
}
```

If I run this with GDB I can see that the power variable has the values of 1 and then 16.

What is the problem here? The function outputs the correct value, I can see the correct value in the debugger so why can't I see the correct values??

Thanks

Edit: 
Added power variable type

Edit2:
After messing a bit more with printfs specifiers I discovered that I should have used %f specifier.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is `power` a `float` or a `double` ? If it is a float, you need to use `%f` instead of `%lf` for printing it.

Comment: post a self-contained example.

Comment: @NiBZ, no. `l` has *no* effect on `f` or any other floating point specifier, becasue floats are upgraded to doubles automagically.

Comment: What is the type of `ex`? If it is a `long` you need format specifier `%ld` to print it.

Comment: @NiBZ Thanks. Before reading your comment I did try %f. Don't know why I didn't try %f in the first place. I thought that because power was a double I needed to use a different specifier, but no, a simpler %f would have done it. Thanks!

Comment: Antonio, the presence of the `l` (ell) should have zero effect on the treatment of a double, ISO C specifically states that the `l` modifier `has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier`. If removing the `l` was the only thing you changed, your implementation of C is broken.

Comment: Note that `pow` will suffer from floating point rounding. Bit shifting will give you exact values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first check the type of `power`, which you haven't shown.

Disagreements between format specifiers and the variables you pass to `printf` are undefined behaviour, which is why:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int i = 42;
    double d = 3.14159;
    printf("POWER::: %lf\n", i);
    printf("POWER::: %lf\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

can give you:

```
POWER::: 0.000000
POWER::: 3.141590
```

with impunity.

For a more detailed reason *why* these incorrect results can happen, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers/2424554#2424554). It doesn't specifically cover floating point values but the theory is the same. If you tell `printf` to expect one thing then give it a totally different thing, you can hardly complain if it becomes confused :-)

If `power` is an integral type, you need to either change it to a non-integral type, or change the format specifier. One way or another, they should match.

---

In any case, you don't need to resort to floating point at all for this task provided you have a 32-bit integer (and the color codes are all 24-bit). You can just use code like:

```
for (int i = strlen(hexString), mult = 1; i > 0; i--, mult *= 16) {
    c = hexString[i - 1];
    printf("MULT::: %d\n", mult);       
    num += convertHexCharToDec(&c) * mult;
}
```

Comment: @paxdiable I have added the types