# multiple %lu to format ULONG64

Tags: c++

[image]

As the image shows, `nLeftHour` is `0`, `nLeftMinute` is `30`, `nLeftSecond` is `3`, and the result is `00:00:30`.

I know it should be `%02llu` and not `%02lu`, but why it is `00:00:30`????

Answer (score 0):

Mismatching the format specifier and the argument results in undefined behaviour, so *anything* could happen.

What's probably happening in your specific case is that the format specifiers are looking on the stack for three unsigned longs but you've pushed three unsigned long long variables leading to an alignment problem.

But it doesn't really matter *what* the outcome is, bottom line is that you shouldn't be doing what you're doing.

More detail can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers/2424554#2424554) which, now that I think about it, makes this a duplicate despite the different language. So I have to vote to close as a dupe, sorry. But I'll leave the text here (as community) so you understand why.