# Why are the int and float passed in printf going to the wrong positions in the format string?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

printf function  int to %f , float to %d trying to experiment

```
#include<stdio.h>                                              
int main(){                                                    
    int i=10;                                                     
    float x=43.2892f;                                              
    printf("i=%f  x=%d \n",i,x);                               
    return 0;                                                  
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
i=43.289200  x=10
```

Need help to understand why these variables are interchanging ?

Comment: Welcome to Undefined Behavior Land.  Population: `INT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: You can experiment as much as you want, but the results you are coming up with are totally useless, as it is *undefined behavior* that you are seeing.

Comment: @NathanOliver just nitpicking, but isn't `INT_MAX + 1` just overflowing and not actual UB?

Comment: Well, it's UB, but looking at the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/Wo4wYT) it's pretty clear that the float is passed in a floating-point register and the integer in a regular register, and `printf` presumably looks for the variables in those registers.

Comment: Well for the first parameter you promised to give it a float but gave it an int. For the second you promised an int but gave it a float.

Comment: but it seems the variables are interchanging the values ??

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Isn't signed integer overflow UB?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Signed overflow is UB.

Comment: @narutowindy because it's undefined behavior. It may as well crash or launch a nuclear missile. Anything can happen.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Signed overflow is UB. Unsigned is defined.

Comment: ***but it seems the variables are interchanging the values*** When you have UB anything can happen.

Comment: @NathanOliver didn't know it was properly "undefined". TIL

Comment: if it is undefined behavior it should produce different results each time, but it doesn't look like  that always produces same result as i mentioned above!

Comment: What the commenters mean by saying it is Undefined Behaviour is that it is behaviour for which the c standrd has explicitly stated that there is no definition -i.e. the computer or compiler designers are free to make it do whatever they want, or nothing, or produce some error. Basically it may do this this time on this computer with this compiler, but change one thing and the result might change

Comment: @narutowindy Undefined behavior can do anything. It doesn't have to be random, it can be consistent.

Comment: UB could call in a nuclear strike on your house. It's just not very likely.

Comment: Bets this didn't happen the first dozen times they tried this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHxj-47csUU

Comment: @narutowindy *it should produce different results each time* - sounds to me like you are *defining* the behavior?

Comment: ***if it is undefined behavior it should produce different results each time*** This is a wrong. UB does not have to be different results each time.

Comment: what about gcc how it deal with the situation like this??

Comment: @narutowindy There are two important terms *undefined* behavior and *implementation specific* behavior. While it is completely legit to ask about how GCC will deal with the latter, it really doesn't make any good to ask the same about the former.

Comment: @narutowindy: GCC has warnings for this, which you should enable by compiling with the `-Wall` flag (in this particular case, it's the `-Wformat` warning).

Comment: @narutowindy: enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and the compiler would warn you in your case.

Comment: @Toby: That would be implementation defined or unspecified behaviour. UB goes further: there is no guarantee two identical cases of UB in the same code produce the same results. Or the code can format the harddrive. For code the compiler did warn (or would have if the warnings are enabled), I strongly support the latter behaviour. Would greatly increase code quality. Survival of the correctest.

Comment: @narutowindy: What about the word **undefined** is not clear??

Comment: @You: `-Wall` is not sufficient. `-Wextra -Wconversion` are strongly recommended, too. If strictly conforming code is required, `-Wpedantic` is also a good pick (but it should be used only with standard C options, i.e. C11 or at least c99.

Comment: @Olaf: Agree. And `-Werror`, as well.

Comment: @You: `-Werror` is useful for release builds. Debug builds are better done without, so all modules will compile and not stop after the first module with warnings. But it is a matter of personal preferences and workflow.

Answer (score 13):

What you're doing invokes *undefined behavior*<sup>1</sup>, but looking at [the resulting assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/Wo4wYT) using GCC on a platform with the [System V AMD64 ABI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) we might formulate a hypothesis. The floating-point value is passed in the `xmm0` register (an SSE register), while the integer is passed in the `esi` register (a general register). Presumably, your `printf` implementation expects floating-point numbers to be passed in SSE registers and integers to be passed in general registers, and simply picks the `xmm0` register to read from when it encounters the first `%f` (and vice versa).

---

<sup>1</sup> *Undefined behavior* does not have to be "random" or "different every time". In this case the undefined behavior is quite consistent. Undefined behavior might even be exactly what you expected to happen; but it might also change when you upgrade your compiler.

Comment: This supposes an x86-64 architecture, and some ABI for it

Comment: How did we get there? Maybe deep in the guts of the implementation something looked at what got passed in and what was requested and figured, "Ehhhh. Programmer screwed up. Me fix."

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Added that assumption to the text.

Comment: @user4581301: This is just part of the ABI. If you pass a float and an int, they go in xmm0 and eax.  If you past an int and a float, they go in eax and xmm0.

Comment: @You which platform has such a weird ABI that passes third arg in `xmm0` but the `printf` implementation is okay with picking the second one from `xmm0` ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya X86, apparently (though I'm not 100% on which calling conventions). The thing here is that the first *floating point* argument is passed in xmm0, and that's exactly where printf has to look to find the first argument that *is a floating point argument* under this calling convention. Had both arguments been things that are passed in general registers, the result would be different.

Comment: @You that is what I find funny. Usually registers are tied to argument number. Like Windows fast call has rcx, rdx, r8, r9 for non float and xmm0, xmm1, xmm2, xmm3 for floats. So if float is third it will go in xmm2 (irrespective of whether it is the first float or not). And the integer would go in rdx.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: For reference, it's the [System V AMD64 ABI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) that behaves like this. Each floating-point argument uses "the next available vector register". Microsoft has a different x86-64 calling convention which works as you describe (and additionally [duplicates the floating-point value into the general register, for vararg functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/varargs)).

Comment: @You I was referring to the "fast call" convention, which is the default for Windows 64 programs. I tried compiling the code here on the same and the float actually went up in xmm2 and the integer went in rdx. About System V AMD64 ABI, it behaves like you said. Thanks for clearing it.