# printf of a int variable with lld, ld and d type identifiers

Tags: c, printf

As I think, %d in printf will read sizeof(int) from the stack, and %ld will read sizeof(long) from the stack, and so on for %lld. I wrote this code snippet:

```
##############printf1.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    long la = 1, lb = 2;
    long long lla = 1, llb = 2;

    printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b); 
    printf("a=%ld, b=%ld\n", a, b); 
    printf("a=%lld, b=%lld\n", a, b); 

    printf("la=%d, lb=%d\n", la, lb);
    printf("la=%ld, lb=%ld\n", la, lb);
    printf("la=%lld, lb=%lld\n", la, lb);

    printf("lla=%d, llb=%d\n", lla, llb);
    printf("lla=%ld, llb=%ld\n", lla, llb);
    printf("lla=%lld, llb=%lld\n", lla, llb);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output in my machine was:

```
$ ./printf1
a=1, b=2
a=1, b=2
a=1, b=2
la=1, lb=2
la=1, lb=2
la=1, lb=2
lla=1, llb=2
lla=1, llb=2
lla=1, llb=2
```

How this happened? I think there should be some junk outputs if the variable type and the type identifier don't match.
My machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux cu01 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 22 21:09:27 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My gcc:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
```

ps:
I have read this post:[printf of a size_t variable with lld, ld and d type identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424528/printf-of-a-size-t-variable-with-lld-ld-and-d-type-identifiers) .But the author's problem didn't happen on my test.
As for the author's code:

```
##############printf2.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    size_t temp;
    temp = 100;

    printf("lld=%lld, ld=%ld, u=%u\n", temp, temp, temp);
    printf("ld=%ld, u=%u, lld=%lld\n", temp, temp, temp);

    return 0;
}
```

The output result on my machine is always "correct":

```
$ ./printf2
lld=100, ld=100, u=100
ld=100, u=100, lld=100
```

Can someone make an explanation on these? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Type mismatch in `printf` invokes *undefined behavior*. Compilation results (assembly code) should be examined to inspect why this result is obtained in this environment.

Comment: The read source need not be the stack. Some calling convension use registers to pass arguments.

Comment: Many modern calling conventions (including, AFAIK, those for the popular Intel processors) pass the first few ordinary values in registers, not on the stack.  So you totally can't used stack-based thinking to predict the results.  (And since the results in this case are *undefined*, trying to predict them is basically a perilous exercise anyway.)

Comment: See also the bizarre situation asked about in [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571175/why-are-the-int-and-float-passed-in-printf-going-to-the-wrong-positions-in-the-f), which seems totally impossible until you realize the arguments are being passed in registers, at which point it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Can't we just acknowledge that undefined behaviour is *undefined* already. There is no point in making sense of it, except that it might be helpful in tracking *bugs* at which point knowing the possible *symptoms* might help find the *cause*.

Comment: The more you *assume* something from the C implementation, the *worse* code you're going to write.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the reply. The stack model can't explain the problem I met, so I thought  there might be some reason I didn't know. Now, I realise that it's **undefined behavior**, and trying to seek the back reason seems not very meaningful.

Comment: Use values that have some bits set in any byte, like 0x12345678, and the format "%x". You will see chopped values even with parameters in registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really happens because of a combination of how these values are passed to printf, and how they are read. So first of all the reason you get the correct result when passing it to printf using the `d` specifier is because its only reading the first 4 bytes out of your 8 byte integer, it just so happens to be that the number 1 only takes up one byte so regardless of how many bytes it reads it would print 1. Here's an easy way visualize it.

here's what your long (and long long) number looks like in binary

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
                                   |-----------------------------------|
```

the above shows the bits that are read when you pass it using `d` as the specifier, if you were to pass `ld`, or `lld` as the specifier it would read the remaining 4 bytes, but as they are all leading zeroes this obviously doesn't affect the printed result. This same concept applies to the number 2. Try replacing the value of `la`, and `lla` with `LONG_MAX` and you'll notice that it prints `-1` when used with the `d` specifier. Note that this behavior is undefined because it depends on the system's endianness, and it would not occur on all systems, this is just what's most likely happening on your system.

Now, why does this not ruin the stack? it obviously should if we're not being honest about the size of things being passed to the stack right? Well since you're on a Linux system your machine is using the System V abi, which specifies in it's calling convention that the first few arguments are to be passed using registers, so nothing in this case is actually being pushed onto the stack, and it's all being read from registers. Here's some more info if you want to read more about it https://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Conventions

It's important to note that this result in different results on different machines, which is obviously why it's called undefined behavior, and why you should not rely on it or use it in your code at all, especially when its so easy not to in situations like this.

Comment: Your explanation of the bits depend on endianness.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't even think about. I edited to comment to reflect this.